# R Combining Matrices

Tags: r, math, matrix

I have two Matrices, one is binary (Zero or One) and the other is an integer matrix of the same dimensions, these are square matrices.

I'd like an efficient way of combining them in a specific way, without iteration along each element.

The way I'd like to combine them is to have a resultant matrix from matrix A and matrix B, that for the element, takes the lowest number that is not zero.

Can anyone think of a trick in R to achieve this, I've tried to do it mathematically but keep coming up short, I was wondering if there was a way to overlay the matrices with a conditional statement?

Comment: What happens if both A and B are 0?

Comment: I think you owe us an example with the expected output.

Comment: @flodel Dwin's solution was what I was aiming to do. The 0,0 instance as seen at matC[1,3] in said solution would be an erroneous result but shouldn't occur in theory. I'd like to give you a more comprehensive example but as I'm ironing out the theory behind it this week, the process isn't in my head enough to do that. I'd be happy to follow up in a week or so. In a broad sense, this is going to be something used for building a gene interaction network.

Comment: ...but `matC[1,3]` is not a `(0, 0)` instance, it is a `(0, 1)` instance. So I expected the result to be `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 matA <- matrix(-8:7, 4,4); set.seed(123)
 matB <- matrix(sample(0:1, 16, repl=TRUE), 4, 4)
 matC <- matrix(NA, nrow(matA), ncol(matA))
 matC[] <- pmin( matA, MatB)
 matC[ matB==0] <- matA[matB==0]

 matB
#-----------
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    1
[2,]    1    0    0    1
[3,]    0    1    1    0
[4,]    1    1    0    1
 matC
#---------
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   -8   -4    0    1
[2,]   -7   -3    1    1
[3,]   -6   -2    1    6
[4,]   -5   -1    3    1
```

flodel's method produces:

```
> ifelse(matB == 0, matB, pmin(matA, matB))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0   -4    0    1
[2,]   -7    0    0    1
[3,]    0   -2    1    0
[4,]   -5   -1    0    1
```

mnel's method produces:

```
> (matB * !matA) + matA
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   -8   -4    1    4
[2,]   -7   -3    1    5
[3,]   -6   -2    2    6
[4,]   -5   -1    3    7
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but unfortunately, while it was exactly what I was aiming to do on my smaller datasets, when I scaled it up to my large datasets, I long Vector error :(

Comment: Both matA and matB were `0` so there really is not another option.

Comment: No, if I run your code `matA[1, 3]` is `0`, `matB[1, 3]` is `1`, yet `matC[1, 3]` is `0`.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not at a machine with R but my wetware execution agrees with your logic. Maybe the conditional in [] should be `matA==0|matB==0`. Untested.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is:

```
ifelse(A == 0, B, pmin(A, B))
```

or maybe

```
ifelse(A == 0, B, ifelse(B == 0, A, pmin(A, B)))
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please clarify (and maybe provide an example.)

Answer (score 1):

From @A_Skeleton's comment on scaling, you could break your matrix into chunks:

```
mnel <- function(matA, matB) {
  (matB * !matA) + matA
}

# method takes a function as the argument
mcombine <- function(matA, matB, method) {
  chunkSize <- 10000
  matC <- matrix(0, nrow(matA), ncol(matA))
  for (i in 1:floor(nrow(matA) / chunkSize)) {
    curRange <- (chunkSize * (i-1) + 1):(i * chunkSize)
    matC[curRange,] <- method(matA[curRange,], matB[curRange,])
  }
  # handle case where dimensions don't divide exactly into chunks
  lastRange <- i*chunkSize:nrow(matA)
  matC[lastRange,] <- method(matA[lastRange,], matB[lastRange,])
  matC
}

# Using mnel's method:
matC <- mcombine(matA, matB, mnel)
```